# What type of exception should I use for a repeated 5XX response codes being thrown in scala?

Tags: scala, exception

**In short**

What type of exception should I throw if a http request keeps returning a 5XX response code in scala?

**Long form**

I have code that retries http requests because I work with some endpoints that aren't very reliable. These retries tend to work. But sometimes I just keep getting 5xx for 408 errors and need to throw an exception. Currently I have a placeholder of an IOException in the code below.

```
def requestRetrier
...
try {
  responseObject = request(url, headers, payload, requestMethod, connectTimeout, readTimeout)
  if ((List(500, 503...) contains responseObject.responseCode) && (retries != 0)) {
    responseObject = requestRetrier(
      url = url,
      headers,
      payload,
      requestMethod,
      connectTimeout,
      readTimeout,
      retries - 1)
  } else if ((retries == 0) && (List(500, 503...) contains responseObject.responseCode)) {
    throw new java.io.IOException
  }
....
```

Comment: Why not just create a custom exception and throw that? Something like `throw new RetriesExceededException(s"Failed to get response after $retryCount tries.")`

Comment: @DanW I think that is the correct answer.

Comment: I've added that as an answer. If it works for you please accept so the question doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create a new custom exception to be more specific and throw that.

Something like:

```
case class RetriesExceededException(message: String) extends Exception(message)
```

Then, you can use it in your example as:

```
} else if ((retries == 0) && (List(500, 503...) contains responseObject.responseCode)) {
    throw RetriesExceededException(s"Failed to get response after $retryCount tries.")
}
```